# How to implement regular lattice of "holes" in a periodic system?

Tags: fortran

I am trying to implement specific type of geometry in a simulation for my work.

My system is a rectangle stripe that has edge-boundaries in the y-direction and periodic in the x-direction.

My code involves using a finite difference method on a grid of `NN x NN` points.
The simulation area is `size_x * size_y`, so i have grid elements of `(size_x/nn) * (size_y/nn)`, THIS NEEDS TO BE A SQUARE GRID ELEMENT.

I then need to have some lines of code where I can place holes of radius=R seperated by a periodic distance=W, but these holes need to be periodic across the periodic boundary in the x-direction.

The image below i created with code that follows later, but the code does not allow me to quickly and freely change R and W. I must change the code manually to suit the hole configuration I want. IT IS IMPORTANT TO NOTE THAT THE SIZE_X AND SIZE_Y CAN BE CHANGED IN ORDER TO SUIT THE PERIODICITY.

[This is the image I refered to above, please see this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvvx6.jpg)

I've attempted a few different methods, but I am struggling to comprehend the method need to implement this, hence joining SOF today and asking some of you guys.

Below I show you the  Fortran code that I have that was able to generate the geometry seen in the picture above.

```
size_x=30.d0            
size_y=30.d0      !!! Simulation area

wstr=20.0d0       !!! Width of stripe (y-direction), periodic in x-direction ù

nn=128        !!! number of grid points

grid_step = size_x/nn !!! Units of xsi(T)      
antidot_period = 6.d0 !!! Units of xsi(T)      xsi(T) is just some length
antidot_radius = 1.d0 !!! Units of xsi(T)

W = int(antidot_period/grid_step) !!! Hole period
R = int(antidot_radius/grid_step) !!! Hole Radius

do k=int(nn/2 - W),int(nn/2 + W),int(W)            
        do n=int(W/2+1),int(nn-(W/2)),int(W)
         do i=int(-R),int(R),1
          do j=int(-R),int(R),1
           iss(k+i,n+j)= 0
           end do
         end do
        end do
end do
```

So I need some way of changing this bit of code such that I can enter any value of `antidot_period` and `antidot_radius` and have a real periodic geometry that is symmetrical about the central X and Y axis; like seen in the image I provided.

If someone can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
antidot_period = 6.d0 !!! Units of xsi(T)
antidot_radius = 1.d0 !!! Units of xsi(T)
nod_in_X = 5.0d0          !!! Number of anti dots in the x-direction

grid_step = 0.25d0

W = int(antidot_period/grid_step) !!! Antidot period ---  Integer value used for antidot creation loop at line 130
R = int(antidot_radius/grid_step) !!! Antidot Radius ---  Integer value used for antidot creation loop at line 130

size_x= (nod_in_X * antidot_period) +antidot_period  !!! Size of the simulation region in x-direction in units of xi(T)
size_y= size_x        !!! Size of the simulation region in y-direction in units of xi(T)

nn = int((nod_in_X/grid_step)*antidot_period)     !!! number of grid points, has to be a power of 2 for fft

do k=int(nn/2 - W),int(nn/2 + W),int(W)            
do n=int(W/2),int(nn-(W/2)),int(W)
do i=int(-R),int(R),1
do j=int(-R),int(R),1
iss(k+i,n+j)= 0       !!! Basically inserts a hole
end do
end do
end do
end do
```